# "SW REV CHECK FAIL : Fused 1 > Binary 0" error while using ODIN

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, odin

I have Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Plus (SM-G928I). It was stuck while updating to Android 7.0. Tried ODIN, but still, it was stuck in the boot loop. So I decided to downgrade it to Android 6.0, but in ODIN, I am getting the following error: `SW REV CHECK FAIL : Fused 1 > Binary 0`.

how do I fix this?

Comment: In most cases you can't downgrade using official firmwares. Find a 7.0 firmware for use with Odin.

Comment: i did . it says success but still stuck in samsung logo

Comment: Now boot into recovery then perform a factory reset. Should pass now.

Comment: Related on XDA Forums: [SW REV CHECK FAIL : Fused 1 > Binary 0](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/sw-rev-check-fail-fused-1-binary-0.2555284/)

Answer (score 2):

It happens sometimes after an update/update that the phone sticks into a bootloop if the data partition is not formatted. 
So to solve this, you simply need to reset your phone from the recovery menu.

Boot in to the recovery then perform a factory reset. The first boot may take some time, just wait.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to downgrade which is not allowed by the bootloader.